# How load columns via ajax in tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to load columns in a tabulator 4.5 using the following:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#tables", {
    ajaxURL:"worker.php?data",
    ajaxRequestFunc:queryRealm,
    cellEdited:cEdit,
    history:true,
    clipboard:true,
    //autoColumns:true,
    clipboardPasteAction:"replace",
    layout:"fitData",
    columns:getColumns,
});

function getColumns(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        $.ajax({
            url: "worker.php?columns",
            success: function(data){
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function(error){
                reject(error);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

But I get the error:

```
tabulator.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: this.options.columns.slice is not a function
    at t.u._clearObjectPointers (tabulator.min.js:4)
    at t.u._create (tabulator.min.js:4)
    at new t (tabulator.min.js:4)
    at (index):84
```

Tell me please, how can I load columns into a tabulator via ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass an async function into the columns parameter.  It expects an array of columns.

So instead of passing `getColumns` into the columns option, you should get the value from `getColumns` and then pass that into the Tabulator options.

I re-arranged your code some, I believe this should work.

```
function getColumns(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        $.ajax({
            url: "worker.php?columns",
            success: function(data){
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function(error){
                reject(error);
            }
        })
    });
}

getColumns().then((columns) => {
  var table = new Tabulator("#tables", {
    ajaxURL:"worker.php?data",
    ajaxRequestFunc:queryRealm,
    cellEdited:cEdit,
    history:true,
    clipboard:true,
    //autoColumns:true,
    clipboardPasteAction:"replace",
    layout:"fitData",
    columns:columns,
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, but then for some reason I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: getColumns.then is not a function

Comment: ...it should be getColumns().then. I will modify the example.